# Custom settings with jshint-rhino.js

Tags: javascript, rhino, jslint, jshint

I've been using jshint with node but just recently had to switch over to using it with Rhino.

I used to be able to do:

`jshint --config=jsHintConfig.json fileToLint.js`

Now, I've tried replacing that call with:

`rhino jshint-rhino.js --config=jsHintConfig.json  fileToLint.js`

But it doesn't seem to work.  I only get the following printed to the console:

`Usage: jshint.js file.js`

Does jshint-rhino not accept a json configuration file?

Update:

http://anton.kovalyov.net/2011/03/01/jshint-edition-update/
- Says: "Added support for providing options to JSHint as command line arguments when used with our Rhino wrapper" but doesn't say how.

https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/27
- Something about specifying options on the cli, but also doesn't say how.

Comment: Still interested in finding a way to do this with Rhino & a config file if possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977878/using-a-config-file-for-jshint-with-rhino

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked:

> rhino jshint-rhino.js file1.js file2.js opt1=true,opt2=true,opt3=false global1,global2,global3

No need to put a comma between file names and it is important to not have spaces before or after the commas for the options and globals.