# Using a config file for JSHint with Rhino

Tags: javascript, rhino, jshint

I'm attempting to run jsHint from the command line using Rhino.  I want to make the check an automatic part of my teams checkin process.

I have the basic configuration working using the command:

```
java -jar .rhino.jar ./jshint.js ./samplefile.js
```

That outputs the standard jsHint messages for my (intentionally error-ridden) sample file.  And adding config comments to the top of the sample file works correctly.  However I would like to add a project level config file to specify the options I want for each file without adding comments to each individual file.

I found instructions to do so for the node.js command line based tool, but have been unable to replicate this with the Rhino wrapper.
I attempted various variations on:

```
java -jar .rhino.jar ./jshint.js ./samplefile.js --configure=./config.js
```

but that didn't seem to work for the rhino version.
Any pointers?

#### UPDATE:

Found [this question (Custom Settings with jshint-rhino)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588643/custom-settings-with-jshint-rhino-js) from a few weeks ago.

This pointed out that the following format works:

```
java -jar .rhino.jar ./jshint.js ./samplefile.js option1=true option2=false global global
```

This worked for me, however I would like to specify a large amount of options and have it be easily configurable, so I would very much prefer to use a json config file as in the node.js distribution.

Could somebody confirm that this is possible/not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, our Rhino wrapper is pretty basic and doesn't support config files. It would be nice to have that—perhaps you would like to create a ticket?